How can I see command-line Test Results in Visual Studio Test Explorer
I'm working on this for days with no progress.
I have a test project with about 200 tests.
When I run via VS all is perfect.
I want to run the tests from code (a custom CRM written in .net).
I tried using dte/marshal but I couldn't get it to work. many errors regarding invalid class etc.
Now I'm trying via command line (Process.Start). I manage to get the tests to run. But Test Explorer does not reflect the progress. I need to be able to look at Test Explorer as the tests are running and see how we're doing.
For starts I'm trying this directly from cmd:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\VSTest.Console.exe" "MY_TEST_PROJECT\bin\Debug\net6.0\WebTests.dll" /TestAdapterPath:"MY_PACKAGES_PATH\packages" /Logger:console;verbosity=detailed

The tests run perfectly. the cmd window show the progress. but Test Explorer stays the same. all tests remain blue (not run)
How can I programmatically start tests, while having the results update in Test Explorer?
FWIW, here's my csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.59" />
    <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp" Version="5.5.13.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Spire.PDF" Version="10.3.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform" Version="17.8.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..MY_LIBRARY\MY_LIBRARY.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Administration">
        <HintPath>\\MY_ASSEMBLIES\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Management">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Management.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>

What I've tried:

Reinstalling NUnit3TestAdapter
Rebuilding, Cleaning solution
Deleting ComponentMountCache
Using dotnet vstest

I also tried:
dotnet test MY_TEST_PROJECT\WebTests.csproj

Tests run okay. UI is not updated.
for completeness, here's the dte code, which theoretically might work. but it grabs a random instance of VS. I may have several open VS instances at any give time:
Sub RunAllTestsInVisualStudio()
Dim dte As EnvDTE80.DTE2 = Nothing
Try
    dte = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE"), EnvDTE80.DTE2)
    If dte IsNot Nothing Then
        dte.ExecuteCommand("TestExplorer.ShowTestExplorer")
        dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.CleanSolution")
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.Build(True)
        'ClearTestResults()
        dte.ExecuteCommand("TestExplorer.RunAllTests")
    End If
Finally
    If dte IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dte)
End Try

End Sub
How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Why not use dotnet test? It is a command line tool and lots of options to control restore, build, logging, filtering, ...

Hi. Thanks. I tried that now. same results. Tests run okay, but Test Explorer UI does not reflect this. What else can I try? Thanks again.

dornet test runs independently of VS, but that makes it much easier to integrate with other tools (eg. in CI/CS pipelines). Rather than using VS to run tests and scrape the results; use the CLI to get the results directly into your tooling (this could include using a custom logger).

Hi. Thanks again. True. I'm aware of these advantages. If I want to go that route, I can use any of the command-line apps mentioned. But currently it's important for me to see the results in VS Test Explorer. Any ideas?

Just run the tests in VS when you're developing. Run in your automation when doing automation. The tests are the same...

Hi Thanks. in the end after hours with gpt and claude I finally got a working function. But I understand its not allowed to post here. so if anyone needs it, we'll have to think of a way to send it. I do appreciate your help though. all the best.
